# @ Operator on variable of type Func<T>

Tags: c#, wpf

So I was digging through some code and I saw something along these lines.

```
Func<T> @delegate = ...
```

My question is what is the @ operator used for in this case?

I've seen it used when creating string literals but never when referencing something other than a string.

Comment: `delegate` is a **key word**, you can't put `Func<T> delegate =`

Comment: Well whomever wrote this line of code did and it compiles just fine.

Comment: Ohhh you're saying the @ symbol makes it a valid variable name.... Who the hell would do this....

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Sometimes a descriptive variable name happens to coincide with a language keyword.  It's nice that the language provides a way to escape the keywords into usable identifiers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Func<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a generic delegate in C#.

[`delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx) is a reserved word in C# so the developer prefixed it with **@** to use it as a valid variable name.

You will see it in asp.net MVC project for HTML helpers where for setting class we use `@class` as class is a reserved word in C# so we can't have a variable with name `class`